# Boxing sparring without punching back

Tags: boxing

I'm 52 and have recently started Judo training which I really enjoy, but have considered trying boxing training for abit more excitement/danger side of it.

I did boxing training for a year when I was a boy, but didn't really enjoy hitting people then, so I gave it up.

So just wondered if I could spar defensively without attack, whilst keeping in mind the fighters would hopefully look after me, given my inexperience.

Would the trainers be OK with that?

Also, what do you think about the health side of boxing for over 50's?

Thanks

Comment: First question: Is it the throwing of punches that you don't want to do at all, or are you okay with throwing punches so long as they don't make hard contact with an opponent? If it's the latter, how much contact is acceptable to you (none, light, or medium)? Second question: Do you want to spar, or are you okay with just doing drills?

Comment: Also, general advice, your bone density stops increasing after about age 30, so be wary of any training that purports to strengthen your bones by repeated impacts. You can, however, strength and muscles and ligaments, but that's done through less trauma and more exercise.

Comment: I'm 55 and still compete in martial arts, love it. Health is fine, just avoid head damage like all ages should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any decent coach will ensure the safety of fighters remains their top priority.  If you ever feel as though your wellbeing or that of other fighters is being neglected, find a new gym.

As far as sparring goes, offence is actually a vital component of defence, so you're better off learning to throw punches as well as how to block, parry and move, even if defence is your primary objective. Your sparring partners will want to learn defence as well, so they will need you to provide an offensive challenge. Trust that your trainer will keep the intensity of your efforts in check.

Most good coaches will not let you spar until you have at least a rudimentary grasp of the basics and will gradually expose you to more intense sessions as you become more skilled and conditioned. It's not a process to be rushed, and one that can be conducted with a fair degree of safety for both fighters.

Regular sparring contains considerable risk of not just minor injury, but [Chronic Traumatic Encephalopathy](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/chronic-traumatic-encephalopathy/#:%7E:text=Chronic%20traumatic%20encephalopathy%20(CTE)%20is,are%20based%20on%20ex%2Dathletes.)

Sparring for recreational fighters is in my opinion best performed lightly, where the emphasis is on technique,  strategy and movement rather than damage. Don't get sucked into a macho environment where 'being tough' is associated with being silly enough to fight on despite repeated concussive blows (this isn't common in good gyms, but the warning is worthwhile).

As for being over 50, boxing can offer an excellent physical and mental regime. Consult a doctor and get a medical check if you are overweight or have any concerns about your health.

Lastly, many trainers know a lot about boxing but little about exercise physiology, especially how it relates to the often unique demands of older athletes. Emulate the tortoise rather than the hare and have confidence in your ability to read warning signs of injury or overexertion. Push yourself, but don't let yourself be pushed beyond what feels safe.

Otherwise, go for it. The benefits can be wonderful.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Any health advice depends on your individual health condition. In principle, I would say you'll definitely benefit from it, especially, as boxing emphasizes on cardio whereas judo is more strength endurance. Hence, I'd say boxing will be easier/better to learn from a physical point of view. It is, at least, definitely safer for your body.
However, this excludes sparring which is also very dependent on the specific gym. A proper gym/coach/athlete would respect your skills and condition but from my experience this is much less present in boxing than e.g. in judo. The people in judo are the most considerate ones I've experienced whereas in boxing, thai boxing and the like are the least ones. I wouldn't expect too much consideration in sparring. I don't think they will hit you (very) hard but once you hit them multiple times (even a bit harder than you wanted to), they will tremendously take less care.

So my advice: I would focus on Judo and Boxing but for sparring in boxing wait 6-12 months to get a proper feeling of the people and gain according skills.